# Nonflammable epoxy remover that won't chip paint

Tags: everyday-chemistry, solvents

I was wondering if anyone knew of a nonflammable epoxy remover that also won't chip paint. My professor wants to use it in our lab to remove dried epoxy from the floors and the fume hood.

Comment: I find it a bit bizarre that a chemistry professor needs to outsource this query to someone. VTC.

Comment: I recommend elbow grease. Very low flammability.